# HibernateTemplate throws NoSuchMethodError in Spring 3.1.1 - Hibernate 4.1

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

When I try using HibernateTemplate I get the following exception:

```
Mar 08, 2012 7:22:14 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/yblob] threw exception [Handler processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.doGetSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:324)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.getSession(SessionFactoryUtils.java:235)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.getSession(HibernateTemplate.java:457)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:393)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.execute(HibernateTemplate.java:339)
    at com.yblob.persistence.HibernatePersistenceManager.browsePublicationRecords(HibernatePersistenceManager.java:102)
    at com.yblob.service.HibernateDAOImpl.browsePublicationRecords(HibernateDAOImpl.java:70)
    at com.yblob.controller.BrowsePublicationRecords.handleRequest(BrowsePublicationRecords.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:101)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Something I have noticed is that it uses `org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils` instead of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils`

my sprint-servlet.xml points to the correct version as follows:

```
<beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
<beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.yblob.persistence.entities" />
<beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
    <beans:props>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</beans:prop>
        <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
    </beans:props>
</beans:property>
```

```
<beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
<beans:property name="sessionFactory">
    <beans:ref bean="sessionFactory" />
</beans:property></beans:bean>
```

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.bbb</groupId>
<artifactId>bbb</artifactId>
<name>bbb</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springframework.security-version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.security-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.12</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.4</org.slf4j-version> 
    <hibernate-version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate-version>
    <cglib-version>2.2.2</cglib-version>
    <log4j-version>1.2.15</log4j-version>
    <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
    <org.codehaus.jackson-version>1.9.4</org.codehaus.jackson-version>
    <net.coobird.thumbnailator-version>0.3.10</net.coobird.thumbnailator-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-asm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Allow Programmatic Configurations -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>${cglib-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet 3 API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.21</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Jackson, JSON support for spring: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${org.codehaus.jackson-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Thumbnalator -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.coobird.thumbnailator</groupId>
        <artifactId>Thumbnailator</artifactId>
        <version>${net.coobird.thumbnailator-version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!-- file upload -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- apache common io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- Hibernate -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>  

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- MySql -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>  

    <!-- Java Mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.4</version>
    </dependency> 

    <!-- CSS Parser -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cssparser</groupId>
        <artifactId>cssparser</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  not sure if necessary -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ezmorph</groupId>
        <artifactId>ezmorph</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  not sure if necessary -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.w3c.css</groupId>
      <artifactId>sac</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--  not sure if necessary -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.security-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>        
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>yblob</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

The answer seems to be on the Spring Forums.

Quote
......

HibernateTemplate isn't recommended for use anymore (about since the release of hibernate 3.0.1) there is no more added value so that isn't going to be in there anymore for hibernate 4. Simply use the plain SessionFactory and use the getCurrentSession method to obtain the current transactional session (don't use openSession!!!!) and you are good to go...

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?117227-Missing-Hibernate-Classes-Interfaces-in-spring-orm-3.1.0.RC1

Comment: What was the actual fix here? I'm getting the same exception from SpringSecurity, and wondering if there's something I can do without needing to patch it in the spring security lib itself..

Comment: Matthew it is a hibernate 3 vs 4 problem.  Is SpringSecurity certified with hibernate 4?

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue when I upgraded Hibernate and Spring versions:

```
nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager$HibernateTransactionObject.setReadOnly(Z)V
```

Issue was due to the different versions of hibernate, Spring-framework, Spring-jdbc dependencies. I Used Spring version 5.2.3.RELEASE and Hibernate version 5.4.10.Final.
That fixed my issue.